# PL/SQL - do not update changed rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I'm planning to do a long running update on my huge table (more than billion rows). This update will multiply one column's values by fixed number.

The problem is that during my update (which may last several hours) there will definitely be short transactions that will update some rows and those rows will have correct value that should not be updated though they will still satisfy my update's condition.

So the question is - how do I skip (do not update) rows that were updated outside my long running update's transaction?

Comment: Let's suppose that short trasactions won't come while you are running the long transaction. But there exist some short transactions which have run and updated some rows before you start the long transaction. So, those rows will be correct. How do you know to skip them? (What I want to say is that your problem has nothing to do size of transaction or concurrency, but data quality and consistency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I absolutely forgot about this question.
So, I ended up making a snapshot of current rows by saving their copies to another table (I had to update only those rows that satisfied given condition). After that I updated rows that haven't changed their values (using merge).

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use **FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED** such that other sessions won't be able to pick the rows which are already picked for update.

For example,

**Session 1:**

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno
  2    FROM emp  WHERE
  3   deptno = 10
  4  FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7782         10
      7839         10
      7934         10

SQL>
```

**Session 2:**

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno
  2    FROM emp  WHERE
  3   deptno in (10, 20)
  4  FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
  FROM emp  WHERE
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

Now let's **skip the rows** which are locked by session 1.

```
SQL> SELECT empno, deptno
  2    FROM emp  WHERE
  3   deptno IN (10, 20)
  4  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7369         20
      7566         20
      7788         20
      7876         20
      7902         20

SQL>
```

So, department = 10 were locked by session 1 and then department = 20 are locked by session 2.

Comment: is this called pessimstic locking ?

Comment: @Moudiz Yes, pessimistic locking in stateful environment.

Comment: But this will not work if session 1 is ran after session 2, am I right?

Comment: @DaniyarKarbaev So what? If you use `SKIP LOCKED` it won't pick the already locked rows, but will pick unlocked rows. Transaction control would be fine. Did you test it or just assuming. I have given a working test case, while you have just explained it words in your question. Ideally, you should show a working test case. So test it yourself and come back with your test case.

Comment: This is not the OP's problem, or not the only(I mean not locking is the problem). See my comment.

Comment: @FlorinGhita OP said, "*The problem is that during my update (which may last several hours) there will definitely be short transactions that will update some rows and those rows will have correct value that should not be updated though they will still satisfy my update's condition.*" So, using a `FOR UPDATE` statement instead of direct update would prevent the short transactions from updating the rows which are already picked by the longer transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like your problem but my table isn't too huge like your.

I re-designed my table, added 2 columns.

created_date: A Trigger put sysdate when insert data.

modified_date: A Trigger put sysdate when update data.

Then I can use created_date or modified_date in my where clause.

Example:

```
UPDATE TABLE table_name
SET column_name = 'values'
WHERE created_date < SYSDATE;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That was my first idea but, unfortunately, modification of table structure is not an option.